# RHC setup fail in OpenShift - UTF8 - SSH

Tags: windows, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am using OpenShift for my studies and in my case the RHC setup does not work.

When I try to execute it, it fails while generating an authorization token saying:

> Generating an authorization token for this client... Only valid UTF-8 encoded inputs are accepted

and then it stops.

My platform is Windows 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue. I fixed it by removing non-ascii characters from my Windows 8 computer name in control panel/system/advanced system settings/computer name/change. Give it a try.